# Nested HTTP calls in angular 4

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular2-observables

I need to make nested http calls in angular 4, Here is my scenario,
The first call is a search api call which returns list of IDs and then I need to loop through the IDs and make another api call using each ID to get details. What is the best method to achieve this using angular 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achive this using RxJs Switch Method, by doing something like this:

```
http.get(/*you params here*/).switchMap(firstResponse => {
    let idsArray = extractArrayFromResponse(firstResponse);
    // Loop through Array
    let arrayOfObservables = idsArray.map(id => http.get(/*other params*/));
    // Now you need to map it to Obervable of arrays
    let obervableOfArrays = arrayOfObservables.merge().toArray();

    return obervableOfArrays;
})
```

Please check out the documentation of `Reactive Extensions` here:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html

And you are probably using it's JS implementation that can be found here:
https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs

Also, it might be useful in your case to check out `forkJoin` operator as suggested by @cyrix. Find JS implementation here:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Comment: I would suggest to say that your github link is for RxJs version 4, the latest version is this one: https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs and maybe add something about the `forkJoin` operator, because then it waits for all resquests to complete before emitting.

Comment: @eddyP23 Iam getting the error ' Property merge does not exist on type array of observables'

Comment: You need to import `merge` operator, as any other operator on `Observable`s, something like this: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';`